# How to Control which files will be included in DNN Module Install file on project Build

Tags: c#, dotnetnuke

I have made a couple of DNN Modules (DAL2) and I cant control the files in the install zip file. I try to exclude them from the project, bu it still packs them, also I want to add some Icons. I add them to the folder include them in the project but they still don't exist in the install file. Is there a file with a list of all the files that will be included in this install zip. 
P.S. I am using Visual Studio Community 2015

Comment: Are you using my Templates?

Comment: Yes I am using your DotNetNuke 7 C# DAL2 Compiled Module